# Understanding the format of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I know this is a super basic question, but I'm getting mixed up. When creating a matrix, is each row a different vector or each column? In other words, is the first column all the $x_1$ coefficients or is the first row all the $x_1$ coefficients etc?

Comment: it depend on your choice. No rule for that.

Comment: you could view the rows of a matrix as vectors **or** the columns of a matrix as vectors

Comment: When you say *creating a matrix*, what do you mean?  Creating a matrix using a programming language like python?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean when given a linear algebra problem involving solving a system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187663/mathcounterexamples-net points out, first index is the row index, second one is the column. That is the convention used almost everywhere.

However, both the set of rows *and* the set of columns can both be seen as sets of vectors. This is important, once you start seeing matrices as representing linear transformations, instead of just as little rectangular tables of numbers. We talk about the vector space spanned by the row vectors, and the vector space spanned by the column vectors. Things like that.

Comment: If I am talking about a matrix representing a linear system of equations, with a solution set attached (making it an augmented matrix), is the first column x_1,x_2,x_3 of one vector or is it x_1,x_1,x_1 of different vectors?

Comment: Typically we see the rows of a linear system of equations as vectors, each vector corresponding to 1 equation. So in that case, you would put the first coordinates of the vectors in the first column. So that would be your second option in your comment.

In general, though, you could have it either way. It depends on what you're trying to do, and what your matrix represents.