# Creating a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802945/understanding-the-format-of-a-matrix), but more specific. I was given the following question:

> Let $D=\{d_1,d_2\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ be bases for vector spaces $V$ and $W$ respectively. Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation with the property that $T(d_1)=-5b_1-7b_2$ and $T(d_2)=9b_1+4b_2$. Find the matrix for T relative to D and B.

This is a pretty simple question and I just took the transformation properties and made a matrix: $$\left(\begin{matrix}-5&-7\\9&4\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

The answer key has the same answer but with the rows and columns switched:$$\left(\begin{matrix}-5&9\\-7&4\\\end{matrix}\right)$$

Am I wrong? Are these both correct? If they are both correct, don't they change the way the transformation works - especially if it is a larger matrix and not a two by two?

Comment: You're wrong: the columns of  the transformation matrix are the coordinates of the transforms of $b_1$ and $b_2$ in basis $D$. To obtain the image of a vector, you multiply this matrix by the column vector of  its *coordinates* in basis $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is correct. Consider applying your matrix to a basis vector:
$$\begin{pmatrix}-5 & -7 \\ 9 & 4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-5 \\ 9\end{pmatrix}\neq\begin{pmatrix}-5\\-7\end{pmatrix}$$
Generally, the $i$-th column of $T$ corresponds to the image of the $i$-th basis vector.

Comment: So when creating a transformation matrix, each column represents a different vector?

Comment: Yes, each column represents the image of each basis vector. In this particular case, the 1st column of $T$ should equal $T\left(d_1\right)$ and the 2nd column of $T$ should equal $T\left(d_2\right)$.